# How to Deploying Single page application Asp.net in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application, iis-8.5

I am working on a .net SPA application. Its on hot towel template . In my local machine the website opens with default url (http://localhost:8081) . Now when I deploy this in IIS . I followed the same steps we follow when we deploy a Asp.net web application . But I see page cannot be displayed error . I am unable to narrow down the cause .

Appreciate your suggestions .

Comment: Whether the app has one or a million pages does not matter for troubleshooting. Obtain the actual error and fix that.

Comment: Sir I am unable to obtain the error . Nothing is getting logged in then event viewer . Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved . It was due to the odp I was using . Mismatch of odp was the reason of this issues . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check your configure files and the verify proper write permissions. The application pool could be needing a tweak.

Comment: I have given full control to iis users and other users on the wwwroot folders . Can you please be more specific on what you mean by write permissions..